# SQL Query Merge 2 into 1

Tags: sql

How could i merge the 2 queries below into 1 with a 4th column to calculate the percentage between column counts 2 and 3

```
Select DISTINCT ASSN, COUNT(REAPING_GROUP_CODE) as TotalGroups
FROM ReapingGroups
GROUP BY ASSN
Order by ASSN


Select  ASSN, COUNT(REAPING_GROUP_CODE) as Groups
FROM ReapingGroups
WHERE  EXISTS (Select * FROM DeliveryTons where reaping_code = REAPING_GROUP_CODE AND remarks = '')
GROUP BY ASSN
```

Comment: update your question add  a  proper data sample and the expected  result  .. please

Comment: Homework? What have you tried? When you post your code, please explain what isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a hack here, but it should get you what you're looking for:

```
select ASSN, sum(TotalGroups) as TotalGroups, sum(CAST(Groups AS DECIMAL)) / sum(CAST(TotalGroups AS DECIMAL))*100.00 as Percentage
from
(
  (
   Select DISTINCT ASSN, COUNT(REAPING_GROUP_CODE) as TotalGroups, 0 as Groups
   FROM ReapingGroups
   GROUP BY ASSN
  )
  union all    
  (
    Select  ASSN, 0 as TotalGroups, COUNT(REAPING_GROUP_CODE) as Groups
    FROM ReapingGroups
    WHERE  EXISTS (Select * FROM DeliveryTons where reaping_code = REAPING_GROUP_CODE AND remarks = '')
    GROUP by ASSN
  )
) NamedSubQuery
group by ASSN
order by ASSN;
```

Comment: Im getting an invalid column name 'ASSN' Invalid column name TotalGroups, Groups as well as incorrect syntax near groups at the bottom

Comment: Hmm, does it tell you which line those invalid columns are on?  Doing this without an editor myself since I do not have access to the tables in your query.  I may have mis-typed a bit, but the general idea is to form the two queries into a single data-set using the union.  Then manipulate your data to get the percentage and regroup it properly using a select from that set of data.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to name the subquery.  Does the edited solution work?

Comment: No           Now im getting :  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 'NamedSubQuery'.

Comment: Hah, found a missing right paren at the end of the WHERE EXISTS piece...  Added that in there now.  Difficult to do this without the editor, sorry.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for your help but still getting an error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'ReapingGroups'.

Comment: I'm not sure on that one - ReapingGroups is the name of the main table you're accessing and I don't see a reference to it on line 1.

Comment: If you have any queries or execution directives above the query, make sure there is a semi-colon after it.

Comment: Okay. The sql seems to work only im geting 1,2,1,1,2,1 values in percentage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137719/discussion-between-user681574-and-ivias).

Comment: The issue involved fixing this. Maybe you can update your code - sum(CAST(Groups AS DECIMAL)) / sum(CAST(TotalGroups AS DECIMAL))*100.00 as Percentage

Comment: Great to hear, I've updated it in the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I won't try to write a specific example, since at the time of this writing you haven't shown any sample data or anything, but here's a general technique you can use to combine a conditional count and an unconditional count into a single query:

```
select 
    FieldName,
    count(1) -- Unconditional count
    sum(case when /*condition*/ then 1 else 0 end) -- Conditional count
from 
    TableName
group by
    FieldName;
```

Also, just as an aside: the `DISTINCT` in your first query is superfluous since you're already grouping on the same field, which is enough to guarantee that each unique `ASSN` value gets only one record in the result set.